# In printf function format tags higher then args what will be happen?

Tags: c, printf

Given by a colleague as a puzzle, I cannot figure out how this C program actually compiles and runs.

```
int main()  
{  

    int a=5;  
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",a++,++a,a++,--a,++a);


return 0;  
}
```

Comment: That is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) on many levels. First and foremost [see this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior). Undefined behavior doesn't mean the compiler will error out, but a good one should probably warn about some UB (like passing to few arguments for the formats).

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the ISO standard. `C11 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function /2` states quite clearly, and `printf()` is simply shorthand for `fprintf(stdout)`:

> The `fprintf` function writes output to the stream pointed to by `stream`, under control of the string pointed to by `format` that specifies how subsequent arguments are converted for output. ***If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.*** If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.

So what will happen is, well, just about *anything!* That is, after all, what "undefined" means.

You need to keep in mind that *anything* even includes the possibility that it may work despite your best efforts. Since it's undefined, a compiler is even free to assume you don't know what you want and simply drop the final format specifier from the string. It could also format your hard disk and play the `derisive_laughter.mp3` file through your sound system :-)

Answer (score -1):

Although the behavior is undefined by the C language spec, given most common implementations of C, we can guess what will happen.

`printf` is a *variadic* function, meaning that the number of arguments it takes can vary.   Normally, the number of arguments is determined by the format string, and the implementation of the function will continue to take arguments from the stack as long as they are needed by the format string.

Since there are 6 `%d` and only 5 arguments, the function will take one additional, 4-byte value from the stack, interpret it as an integer, and print it out.

Of course, none of this is guaranteed.  This program already broke the rules, and nasal demons are a valid possibility.   But I think getting garbage output based on part of the stack is a reasonable and likely outcome.

Comment: Depends on whether the sixth integer argument is passed in a register or on the stack. Curiosity: The 64-bit convention for Windows differs fom that of Linux/FreeBSD/Solaris. On Windows, only four int/pointer args are passed in registers but on Linux/etc. six arguments are.